# Show message as well as diff with git stash show

Tags: git, git-stash

Using the command line tool `git-stash`, how can I view both the stash message, as well as the diff, for a given stash?

The documentation for [git stash](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) mentions that you can configure how a diff is shown, but it doesn't mention messages anywhere other than in how to create a stash.

Comment: Do you mean the message that shows up when you run `git stash list`?

Comment: @Chris yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @Downvoter I RTFM'd. What more do you expect me to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A stash is stored as a normal commit, hence you can use usual Git commands to display it, like:

```
git show stash@{1}
```

to show message and diff for `stash@{1}`. Since stashes are stored as commits with two parents (one for the index, and the other for the `HEAD` at the time the stash was created), the command above will show a combined diff.

Obviously, as others already pointed out, `git stash list -p` or `git list` with `stash.showPatch=true` (new in 2.7.0) also show diff + message, for all stashes.

Comment: I get `++` and `--` in the diff rather than `+` and `-`. Is that normal?

Comment: Stash commits are stored with two parents, the git diff show runs is reporting the comparison between the stashed worktree state and the stashed index state as well as the commit that was checked out at the time.

Comment: Note that `stash.showPatch=true` only works for `git stash show`; it has no effect on `git stash list` so you still need `-p` there ([see](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash/2.37.2#Documentation/git-stash.txt-show-u--include-untracked--only-untrackedltdiff-optionsgtltstashgt))

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for a command like

```
git stash list -p
```

This shows the diff of each stash, together with the messages you provided.

**Edit:** In case you know which stash number you want to show (i.e., not show the entire list but one specific stash), you can do

```
git stash list -p -n 1 --skip i
```

where `i` is the number of the stash you want to show. (this will show `stash@{i}`).

As mentioned in [the manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html), the `git stash list` command takes options for formatting similar to `git log`, see the [git log man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

The `-p` option ensures that all the information you want is printed (you can play around with the formatting as explained on the [git log man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html))

The option `-n 1` ensures that only one stash is printed, also see the [git log man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

The option `--skip i` tells git to not print the first `i` stashes, hence, combined with the option `n 1`, only `stash@{i}` will be shown. Again, see the [git log man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Comment: The problem is that it shows all stashes, not just a single stash.

Comment: Indeed, I'll add how to do it for a given stash

Comment: Whoops, you are right! I thought that allowed for the options as well. Hold on a sec ;-)

Comment: This answer is useful, but a bit more verbose than Matthieu's, unfortunately.

Comment: I completely agree :-)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a way to look at the patches/diffs for all stashes in a single command.  Awesome.